# CDI PostConstruct using a service producer

Tags: jakarta-ee, cdi, weld

I'm trying to build an app using Java EE 6. Development is done on TomEE 1.7. For various reasons, I have to create most of my CDI managed objects through a service producer. When I do this, however, the `@PostConstruct` annotated method of the created bean is not invoked. If I take the service producer out of the way and let CDI create the object directly through its constructor, it does get called. Is this normal, or is it a bug of the CDI provider TomEE comes with (Open WebBeans)

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is normal behavior. The `@PostConstruct` method is called, when the bean is initialized by the container. See [Weld Reference](http://docs.jboss.org/weld/reference/latest/en-US/html/injection.html#_injection_points):

> Simplifying just a little, things happen in this order:
>
> - First, the container calls the bean constructor (the default    constructor or the one annotated `@Inject`), to obtain an instance of
>     the bean.
> - Next, the container initializes the values of all injected fields of the bean.
> - Next, the container calls all initializer methods of bean (the call order is not portable, don’t rely on it).
> - Finally, the `@PostConstruct` method, if any, is called.

However in case of producer method you have full control, how the object is created, so you can call any needed method by yourself. Take notice, that in producer methods object is usually created using `new`, so annotated fields are not initialized. Again check the [producer method documentation](http://docs.jboss.org/weld/reference/latest/en-US/html/producer_methods.html) for possible solution (injection into producer methods, `@New`)

Comment: I got it to work by invoking the @PostConstruct method directly in the producer. I had tried that before, but couldn't go through with it because the method depended on other beans injected in the produced one. Finding out that producer methods have their arguments injected filled the gap.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like bad practice to use a producer for everything - why are you using a producer if your classes are annotated with `@PostConstruct`?

One way to do this is to use a creational context from within your producer method to provide a reference and then call post construct on that reference.  Here's some sample code, taken from [Apache DeltaSpike](http://deltaspike.apache.org/), a suite of CDI extensions:

[BeanProvider](https://github.com/apache/deltaspike/blob/master/deltaspike/core/api/src/main/java/org/apache/deltaspike/core/api/provider/BeanProvider.java#L409)

```
    BeanManager beanManager = getBeanManager();

    CreationalContext creationalContext = beanManager.createCreationalContext(null);

    AnnotatedType annotatedType = beanManager.createAnnotatedType(instance.getClass());
    InjectionTarget injectionTarget = beanManager.createInjectionTarget(annotatedType);
    injectionTarget.inject(instance, creationalContext);
    injectionTarget.postConstruct(instance);
```

Comment: I use a producer because most of the components that get injected in UI beans come in two flavours, and what gets created is decided on runtime parameters. Your sample code seems to tie post construction of the injected bean to the injection point, so for multiple injection points I would need to do some management of which injection point invokes post construction.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean.  What makes you think this?  This is the content of a producer method, for example, once you've instantiated your instance.  `InjectionTarget` is simply an API in CDI that allows you to call `PostConstruct` or `PreDestroy` methods on a managed object.

Comment: Sorry, my interpretation was just guesswork. I assumed that InjectionTarget represents the bean into which the created instance gets injected, and that the code is run when the injection occurs. My bad. When I get some time I'll take a closer look at DeltaSpike, it seems a worthwhile investment